# Apex Batch and Scheduling help

Tags: apex

Hi so what I need to do is create a batch class that will run everyday and check if the `Start_Date__c` of the object `OrderProduct__c` is equals to `Date.Today` then if it's `Date.Today` it will update the `Subscription__c` field in `OrderProduct__c` to `Active`. My scheduling should run everyday at 1am. I already created an batch class and schedulable but I don't know why it's not working. Is there anyway I can test my schedulable in dev console to know that it's working instead of waiting to see if the field changes?

Can someone point me to what is my mistake in my classes for it to not run, It looks perfectly fine to me.

This is my Batch class for `OrderProduct__c` that will update the `Subscription__c` field if `Start_Date__c` is equals to today.

```
    global class SubscriptionBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        // collect the batches of records or objects to be passed to execute
        return Database.getQueryLocator('Select ID,Start_Date__c,Subscription__c from OrderProducts__c');
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<OrderProduct__c> records){
        // process each batch of records
        String ac = 'Active';
        for(OrderProduct__c op : records){
            if(op.Start_Date__c == Date.today()){
            op.Subscription__c = ac;
            }
        }
        update records;
    }    

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
        // execute any post-processing operations
    }    


}
```

then this is my Scheduled batchable class

```
 global class scheduledBatchable implements Schedulable {
  global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
  SubscriptionBatch batch = new SubscriptionBatch(); 
  database.executebatch(batch);
  }
}
```

and then this is my scheduler that I run in developer console

```
    scheduledBatchable batch = new scheduledBatchable();
System.schedule('Scheduled Activation of Subscription', '0 1 * * * ?', Batch);
```

my Kron is 01*** meaning it should run everyday at 1am

Can someone help me thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add condition as `WHERE Start_Date__c = TODAY'` in your getQueryLocator and remove date check condition from if condition:

```
global class SubscriptionBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        // collect the batches of records or objects to be passed to execute
        return Database.getQueryLocator('Select Id, Start_Date__c, Subscription__c from OrderProducts__c WHERE Start_Date__c = TODAY');
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<OrderProduct__c> records){
        // process each batch of records
        String ac = 'Active';
        for(OrderProduct__c op : records){
            op.Subscription__c = ac;
        }
        update records;
    }    

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
        // execute any post-processing operations
    }    
}
```

Refer [Date Formats and Date Literals](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm).

For your [cron expression](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm) use something like:

> System.schedule('Scheduled Activation of Subscription', '0 0 1 * * *', Batch);